# grid , get all stores of a block cms

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, cms-block, stores

I m trying to get all stores of a block cms in an adminhtml page.
But something is wrong :( 
Here is my code :

```
    class Upecom_Brandhub_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Grid
        extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
    {

        /**
         * Get tab label
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return Mage::helper('Upecom_Brandhub')->__('Blocks');
        }

        /**
         * Get tab title
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return Mage::helper('Upecom_Brandhub')->__('Blocks');
        }

        /**
         * Check if tab can be displayed
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Check if tab is hidden
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId('myTabGridBlocks');
            $this->setUseAjax(false);
            $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
            $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
            $this->setEmptyText(Mage::helper('Upecom_Brandhub')->__('No records found!'));
        }
          protected function _prepareCollection()
            { 
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter("brand_id", 500)
                        ->addFieldToFilter("type_block", 6);
         $this->setCollection($collection);

                return parent::_prepareCollection();
            }
          protected function _prepareColumns()
            {
 $this->addColumn(
            'identifier',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('Upecom_Brandhub')->__('Identifier'),
                'width' => '200px',
                'index' => 'identifier',
            )
        );
          if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
                    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                        'header'        => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
                        'index'         => 'store_id',
                        'type'          => 'store',
                        'store_all'     => true,
                        'store_view'    => true,
                        'sortable'      => false,
                        'filter_condition_callback'
                        => array($this, '_filterStoreCondition'),
                    ));
                }
        }
        }
```

It return me all the time nothing in the store columns (but i have everything else )

Comment: Are you able to see your store column in your grid?

Comment: Yes, but not values.
 , i just found the answer (see the asnwer :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I just need to add :

```
protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    $this->getCollection()->walk('afterLoad');
    parent::_afterLoadCollection();
}

protected function _filterStoreCondition($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($value);
}
```